# A strange circle keep appearing since Android 11 Beta update

Tags: android-11, oppo-coloros

Recently I updated my Oppo A9 to the Android 11 beta. Since then, a strange sign keeps appearing in the centre of my screen at random intervals. It appears at the centre of the screen, then it stays there for 1 or 2 seconds, and then it disappears.

[image: this is the cropped screenshot of the sign]

What is it? How to get rid it?